# Fancytree JQuery - Get node children and sub children

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I'm using Fancytree (https://github.com/mar10/fancytree) and I have this tree structure:

```
root
 |_ child1
      |_ subchild1
      |_ subchild2
            |_ subchild3
            |_ subchild4
```

If the the selected node is `child1` I can get the first children using `window.tree.activeNode.children` or `window.tree.activeNode.getChildren()` but that only return `[subchild1, subchild2]`. There are anyway get **all** the children?

A method that return: `[subchild1, subchild2, subchild3, subchild4]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `visit`function to generate a flat list:

```
var activeNode = tree.getActiveNode(),
    nodes = [];

activeNode.visit(function(node) {
    nodes.push(node);  // or node.key, ...
});
```

(Note that there is also the `node.toDict()` method to generate a nested object instead.)